# Нужна помощь по рекурсии

Tags: php

Есть рекурсия в Codeigniter

```
function get_tree($pid)
{
    $this->db->select('id, name, parent_id');
    $this->db->where('parent_id',$pid);
    $tree = $this->db->get("catalog")->result_array();
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
    $html = '';

    foreach ($tree as $row)
    {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $pid)
        {
            $html .= '<li>' . "\n";
            $html .= '    ' . $row['name'] . "\n";
            $html .= '    ' . $this->get_tree($row['id']);
            $html .= '</li>' . "\n";
        }
    }

    return $html ? '<ul>' . $html . '</ul>' . "\n" : '';
}
```

Значит, вызываю так:

```
echo "<ul class='menu'>";
echo $this->leftmenu->get_tree('0');
echo "</ul>";
```

И вот дело такое, рекурсия запускается и пишет в начале новый тег `<*ul>` в результате чего мой класс `menu` не попадает в список. Как быть?
То есть получается вот так вот:

```
<ul class='menu'>
 <ul>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test
     <ul><li>test_2</li>
         <li>test_2</li>
      </ul></li>
   <li>test</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Разобрался.

Answer (score 2):

Перепишите эту строчку:

```
   return $html ? '<ul>' . $html . '</ul>' . "\n" : '';
```

на

```
   return $html ? '<ul class="menu">' . $html . '</ul>' . "\n" : '';
```

А еще лучше - перепишите ее на:

```
   return $html;
```

Тогда ваш код отработает так как вы планировали, ну и, конечно - вы сможете писать те классы какие вам нужны.Ну или, перепишите функцию как-то так:

```
function get_tree($pid, $className = null)
{
    $this->db->select('id, name, parent_id');
    $this->db->where('parent_id',$pid);
    $tree = $this->db->get("catalog")->result_array();
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
    $html = '';

    foreach ($tree as $row)
    {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $pid)
        {
            $html .= '<li>' . "\n";
            $html .= '    ' . $row['name'] . "\n";
            $html .= '    ' . $this->get_tree($row['id']);
            $html .= '</li>' . "\n";
        }
    }

    $ulStart = ($className != null) ? '<ul class="'.$className.'">' : '<ul>';
    return $html ? $ulStart . $html . '</ul>' . "\n" : '';
}
// если переписать так, то вызывается функция так:
      //     get_tree($pId, $className);
      // ------  где className значения атрибута `class`
      // ------  корневого ul эдемента
```

Comment: я сделал так  

    if ($pid > 0)  
    {  
        $ul = "<ul>";  
        $closeul = "</ul>";  
    }    

else {  
        $ul = "";  
        $closeul = "";  
    }    

и возвращаю   
return $html ? $ul . $html . $closeul . "\n" : '';